# Perform shell operation through secure shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ssh, scp

Is it possible to perform a shell operation from a bash script through a secure shell.

Here is an example of why you may want to do this. Lets say you have a simple unix operating system that you need only build and run on, but you want to do all of the development on another machine. I want to write a bash script that has the following functionality:

```
scp file to location on other machine
ssh to other machine
cd into correct directory 
make 
run program
scp results to file on original computer
exit ssh
```

Is this remotely possible? (Pardon the Pun :p)

Comment: ssh user1@server1 '/scripts/backup.sh' will run the script on remote machine. You can simply scp "backup.sh" at required location, invoke ssh and exit

Comment: @UsmanSaleem You should add this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a direct example of your pseudocode,

```
scp file remote:/tmp/file
ssh remote 'cd /tmp; cat file >another; rm another'
scp remote:/tmp/another /tmp
```

Perhaps you want to avoid the use of temprary files; if you can use standard input and standard output for this, you might get away with something like

```
ssh remote 'remotescriptname' <input >output
```

... assuming `remotescriptname` can read standard input, and end up producing the result on standard output.  (You will want to prevent noisy commands like `make` from producing any output on standard output; `make -s` is your friend.)

You'll notice that you can have an abitrarily complex snippet of shell script between the single quotes.  There doesn't need to be a program `remotescriptname` if you prefer to put the entire command line of the individual commands between the single quotes, like in my first example; but you might want to anyway, because a self-contained script is easier to debug and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. For example:

```
$ echo 'date' | ssh localhost
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Password:
Sun Dec 16 22:15:08 CST 2012
```

I suggest you create a script on the remote side that will do the builds and scp back on success to minimize the amount of remote commands you need to send. Also, making a passwordless RSA key will make your life easier too.

EDIT:

While we are on the topic, you may be interested in a few of these programs.

[`distcc`](http://code.google.com/p/distcc/): Distribute builds across multiple machines

[`buildbot`](http://trac.buildbot.net): Automatically build code as it is checked in on any number of machines/OSes and run unit tests, etc.

Answer (score 1):

ssh user1@server1 '/scripts/backup.sh' will run the script on remote machine. You can simply scp "backup.sh" at required location, invoke ssh and exit

Comment: You may copy public keys of your client machine to your server and vice versa so that you don't have to input passwords.